# Can one read Gieseker stability from geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Suppose $X$ is a smooth variety with an ample line bundle $H$. Let $F$ be a vector bundle on $X$ and $E \subseteq F$ be a sub-bundle. Let $\mathbf{P}(F), \mathbf{P}(E)$ be the total space of $F,E$ respectively.

**Question:** Can one read the relation between slopes $\mu(F), \mu(E)$ from the geometry of $\mathbf{P}(F), \mathbf{P}(E)$?

In my case, $\mathbf{P}(F)$ has a clear geometric meaning, and I want to show $F$ is Gieseker stable from this geometric meaning (suppose we only consider sub-bundles of $F$). It seems the problem lies on how to interpret $c_1(F)$ and $c_1(E)$.

Comment: By Proposition 3.3 of "The cones of effective cycles on projective bundles over curves" by Mihai Fulger, if $F$ is slope-unstable (with respect to some chosen ample bundle) then there are two effective cycles of complementary dimension on $\mathbf{P}(F)$ with negative intersection. So if you understand $\mathbf P(F)$ well enough to show no such cycles exist, you can conclude that $F$ is slope-semistable. I don't know about Gieseker stability.

Comment: @potentiallydense.  That property does not characterize slope unstable bundles.  If there exist effective cycles $Y$ and $Z$ on $X$ of complementary dimension that have negative intersection, then for the cycle that is the pullback of $Y$ to $\mathbf{P}(F)$, and for the cycle that is the pullback of $Z$ intersected with $\text{rank}(F)-1$ relative hyperplane classes, the intersection number of these cycles on $\mathbf{P}(F)$ will again be negative.

Comment: @JasonStarr: just to be clear, you're saying that the property that there do not exist such cycles on $\mathbf P(F)$ is sufficient, but not necessary, for slope semistability? If so: indeed, that's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. (Maybe I should have been more clear that I was only providing partial information.) If not, please let me know what I misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.  Maybe it is possible to put some restrictions on the cycles, and that new property will characterize slope-unstability.